# Binary_Search on vector of pars

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to perform a binary sort on a vector of pairs and also return the iterator once found, however I seem to be having an issue with this. Originally I had something like this and t is a vector of type int.

```
if (std::binary_search(t.begin(), t.end(), 5, *it))
{
    if (it != t.end())
    {
        cout << "FOund";
    }
}
```

However this does not seem to work (compilation issue) i think the issue is because I have a pair instead of a normal vector, so was wondering if anyone has any website links on this I can read?##

Error received is below:

> term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Comment: *"However this does not seem to work"* Why not? Does it not compile? Does it produce incorrect results?

Comment: @ShamariCampbell Could you please post your error message?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail? Post the type of `t`, post the full exact compilation error, post an example vector and what element you are trying to match.

Comment: What is `it`?  `it` should be a function or functor.  Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: please mention the error message

Comment: The last parameter should be a comparison function, not a dereferenced iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard algorithm std::binary_search has the following forms

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
bool binary_search(ForwardIterator first, 
                   ForwardIterator last, 
                   const T& value);

template<class ForwardIterator, class T, class Compare>
bool binary_search(ForwardIterator first, 
                   ForwardIterator last, 
                   const T& value, 
                   Compare comp);
```

Thus your call of the algorithm in statement

```
if (std::binary_search(t.begin(), t.end(), 5, *it))
```

and subsequent check

```
if (it != t.end())
```

do not make sense. Moreover if the value type of the vector is `std::pair` then you have to specify an object of type `std::pair` as the third argument.

Instead of the `std::binary_search` you should use either `std::lower_bound` or `std::equal_range`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you really trying to do? How do you want to find *one* integer in an array of *pairs*? You can only find a given *pair* within a vector of pairs.

If you want to find a pair that has given integer as its first or second parameter, you will have to write some code yourself.

To find a given *pair*, read on.

`std::binary_search` can not return an iterator, nor does it accept an iterator as a 4th parameter. As a 4th argument it accepts a comparator, but definitely your `it` it not a comparator.

If you want to obtain an iterator, you should use `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` and *assign* the return value to `it`: `it = std::lower_bound(t.begin(), t.end(), val)`.